# how to remove all non english characters and words using NLTK >

Tags: python, nltk

Guys How we can remove all non-English characters, and words using NLTK if we have input 'Gutenberg frequency list' to the program ?

Plzz help --
karim

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit your question, it is vague.

Comment: @pss how it is vague?

input: Gutenberg frequency list
output: All characters which are in english dictionary

Comment: When I read the whole stuff on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
I concluded that your question is unfortunately vague. :)

Comment: @pss Forgive me - Please help me if you can :P

Comment: @user3541877 You're lucky pss is so nice. People are trying to tell you that your question is _too vague to answer_, not that they don't want to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) before. There could be a better solution too.
In my code snippet I am simply doing the following:

1. Reading a file that needs to be checked for non-english/english words named as `frequencyList.txt` to a variable named as `lines`.
2. Then I am opening a new file named as `eng_words_only.txt`. This file will contain the english words only. Initially this file will be empty, later after executing the script this file will contain all the English language words present in `frequencyList.txt`
3. Now for every word in `frequencyList.txt` I check if it is also present in `wordnet`.
   If the word is present then I write this word to the `eng_words_only.txt` file, else I do nothing. Please see I am using `wordnet` just for demo purpose. It doesn't contains all the English language words!

**Code:**

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

fList = open("frequencyList.txt","r")#Read the file
lines = fList.readlines()

eWords = open("eng_words_only.txt", "a")#Open file for writing

for w in lines:
    if not wordnet.synsets(w):#Comparing if word is non-English
        print 'not '+w
    else:#If word is an English word
        print 'yes '+w
        eWords.write(w)#Write to file 
        
eWords.close()#Close the file
```

**Testing:** I first created a file named as `frequencyList.txt` with the following contents:

```
cat 
meoooow 
mouse
```

then upon executing the code snippet you'll see the following output in the console:

```
not cat

not meoooow

yes mouse
```

Then a file will be created `eng_words_only.txt` which contains only the words that were supposed to be of the English language. The `eng_words_only.txt` will contain only `mouse` word. You may notice that cat is an English word but it is still not in the `eng_words_only.txt` file. This is the reason why you should use a good source instead of wordnet.
**Please note**: The python script file and the `frequencyList.txt` should be in the same directory. Also, instead of `frequencyList.txt` you can use any of your file that you want to check/investigate. In that case don't forget to change the files names in the code snippet too.

**Second Solution**: Although you didn't ask for it but still there is an other way too to do this English word test.

Here is the code: Here the [wordlist-eng.txt](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/wordlist.html) is the file which contains the English words. You have to keep

`wordlist-eng.txt`, `frequencyList.txt` and the python script in the same directory.

```
with open("wordlist-eng.txt") as word_file:
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file)

fList = open("frequencyList.txt","r")
lines = fList.readlines()
fList.close()

eWords = open("eng_words_only.txt", "a")

for w in lines:
    if w.strip().lower() in english_words:
        eWords.write(w)
    else: pass
eWords.close()
```

After executing the script the `eng_words_only.txt` will contain all the English words that were present in `frequencyList.txt` file.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: @pss-- How can we remove all  distinct words of length 16 letters or more. Reduce the size of these words  to fifteen letters while keeping them distinct.  (hint removing postfix, suffix, and or infix)

so far i have done the following code:
<code>
fo = open(“sixteenLetter_words_only.txt”,”wb”) 
words = set(w.lower() for w in open('distinct_words_only.txt').read().split())
for item in english_words
 if len(item) > 15
  fo.write(item)
fo.close()
</code>

Comment: You may create a different question for this problem, then other users can also help you. Please provide all the details in your new question.

Comment: new question created

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131830/how-can-we-remove-all-distinct-words-of-length-16-letters-or-more-using-python