# How can we remove all distinct words of length 16 letters or more using python

Tags: python

How can we remove all distinct words of length 16 letters or more. Reduce the size of these words to fifteen letters while keeping them distinct. (hint removing postfix, suffix, and or infix)

so far i have done the following code:

```
fo = open("anyFile.txt","wb")
words = set(w.lower() for w in open('distinct_words_only.txt').read().split())
for item in english_words:
   if len(item) > 15:
       fo.write(item)
fo.close()
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some commas after the `for` and `if` statements

Comment: @haidro please ignore syntax errors :)

Comment: @user3541877 why? They are a problem with your current code.

Comment: How are you supposed to "reduce the size of these words while keeping them distinct"?  You could truncate them at 15 letters, sure, but what are you supposed to do if they aren't distinct then anymore?

Comment: For example, if you've got `abcdefghijklmnopq`, `abcdefghijklmnopQ`, `Abcdefghijklmnopq`, and `abcdefgHijklmnopq` (so once the `A` is capitalized, once the `Q`, and once the `H`), what output would you expect?  (The capitalization is just used to indicate a change; I'm aware that you only have lowercased words.)

Comment: If you really want to solve this task, then the wording of your question is very misleading while the task itself is very interesting.  So (if this is the case) maybe you should ask another question with a more appropriate wording to draw more attention.

Comment: @Alfe How are you supposed to "reduce the size of these words while keeping them distinct"? You could truncate them at 15 letters, sure, but what are you supposed to do if they aren't distinct then anymore?

Then we need to remove starting letter and check if it has become distinct, then middle and then last letter

Comment: For a large enough input file, it's impossible to trim everything and guarantee uniqueness. For example, if "anyFile.txt" was composed of all possible 15 character strings, plus one 16 character string, there would be no way to trim the 16 character string.

Comment: @Alfe just assume all letters are in small

Comment: Or, even more trivially, what if your file has only two strings: the 15 character "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", and the 16 character "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"?

Comment: @kevin from sixteen characters trim the first charcter -- if it is same to previous 15 charcters then check for middle and then check for last charcter to see the words has become distinct. if nothing works just ignore the word

Comment: @Kevin, I guess you could just trim the 16-X to a 14-X to make it distinct from the 15-X ;-)

Comment: I fear your vague specification on what to do makes the task a very complex one.  If you have _n_ problematic words which all reduce to the same when been just truncated, then you can maybe find a solution for each of the _n_ · (_n_-1) pairs of the _n_ problem words which are not combinable altogether.  To find a solution which solves the task for all _n_ problem words, you've got a complex problem, also because by shortening a problem word it can become a problem word for completely different words in the list.  As I said, an interesting problem, you should reword it and ask a new question.

Comment: @user3541877 Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Well I gave a quick shot to your question. I shall explain how I accomplished this task. There could be a better approach too. As far as what I understood from your question is:

> Your major concern is to keep the length of a word to 15 and also to keep
>   them distinct.

The code snippet below does that exactly. I first read the file `anyFile.txt` which shall contain all the words having 15 letters or more only. I assume from your question that you have already created this kind of file. I kept the contents of this file into `english_words`.

Then I declared a `charList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`. Well in my code I am simply using these `6` letters for creating distinct words. You can use more if you like. More is better.

Then I loop over every word using a for loop. In loop first I strip the word to keep its length up to 15 letters. Then I call my `checker()` to do the heavy stuff.

The `checker()` will first check if the word is already present in `oldWordList` if yes then it will generate a new distinct word. I used recursion to double check if the newly created word is distinct or not. If the word is not in the `oldWordList` then I simply append it to a `newWorldList`.

This `newWorldList` will contain all the distinct words at last.

How are distinct words being generated? 
Well the code is simple. First I am converting the word which is a string to a List `tempList = list(item)`, so that I can modify it. Then here
 `tempList[randomIndex] = charList[randomChar]` 
I am selecting a random letter from `charList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']` and then assigning it to a random position in the `tempList`.

Code snippet:  *Please see: The code snippet is quick and dirty feel free to improve it further.*

```
import random

fo = open("anyFile.txt","wb")
english_words = set(w.lower() for w in open('distinct_words_only.txt').read().split())

for item in english_words:
    if len(item) > 15:
        fo.write(item+'\n')
fo.close()


def checker(item):
    randomIndex = random.randrange(0,15)#Random number to decide which position in word
    randomChar = random.randrange(0,6)#Random number to pick a letter from charList
    if item in oldWordList:
        print 'Yes %s is present already'%item
        tempList = list(item)#Convert string to list
        tempList[randomIndex] = charList[randomChar]#Generate random word
        item = "".join(tempList)#Covert list back to string
        checker(item)#Recursion to double check
        print 'Newly created word %s'%item
    else:
        print '%s is distinct'%item
        newWordList.append(item)

english_words = set(w.lower() for w in open('anyFile.txt').read().split())
charList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
oldWordList = []
newWordList = []
for item in english_words:
    item = item[0:15]
    print 'Append item to oldWordList %s '%item
    checker(item)
    oldWordList.append(item)

print oldWordList#Will contain the original 15 letters words 
print newWordList#Will contain distinct 15 letteres  words
```

**Testing the code:** Create a file named as `'distinct_words_only.txt'` with the following content and execute the script code:

```
averybigblackdogwithdots
averysmallwhitecatwithatail
averytinygreymousewithanose
averytinygreymousewithabignose
averybigblackdogwithdots
averybigblackdogwithdotts
averysmallwhitecatwithalongtail
averytinygreymousewithanosee
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbb
```

When the script is executed you shall see the `print newWordList` will show you a list of distinct words with length of 15 letters in console.

**Limitation:** I just wanted to point out that there is a limitation in creating distinct words too using replacement method like what I did. Eg: Consider a word of 2 letters and if you are allowed to use 2 letters for creating all the possible words then you can only generate 4 different words.

**Eg:**
Word = IN, replacement letters are A,B

Distinct words could only be: IA, IB, AN, BN. Because in replacement method we can only replace a letter without changing their position. We can only replace I or N with A or B. We can't do something like NA, NB, AI, BI etc. using replacement method.

I hope this was a bit helpful.